# Как установить keystore для публикации на google play

Tags: android, unity3d, keystore

В developer console я скачиваю сертификат типа `*.der`, потом с помощью консоли генерирую `*.keystore`, пихаю его в unity, но он не видит alias. Как сделать так, чтобы видел, иначе при сборке приложения выдет ошибку

> "trusted certificate certificates are not password-protected"

Answer (score 2):

Сначала открываем настройки проекта

1. Ставим отметку "Create new keystore" - Создать новое хранилище ключей
2. Нажимаем "Browse Keystore" выбрать путь сохранения
3. Выбираем место сохранения и вводим название файла кейстор
4. Жмем сохранить
5. Вводим пароль для защиты нашего ключа (Пароль на ваше усмотрение) 
   Опускаемся ниже в раздел "Key"
6. Нажимаем "Create a new key" - это будет ключ уже для самого приложения.
   А кейстор, это хранилище ключей.
   В появившемся окне, заполняем поля, можно не заполнять всё подряд, 
   достаточно ввести лишь названия ключа "Alias" и  задать пароль для этого ключа.
7. Нажимаем "Create a new key" 
   Теперь выбираем наш только что созданный ключ, и вводим пароль для него.
8. Вводим пароль который вы задали в пункте 7

Теперь наше приложение имеет нужный keystore

http://unitywiki.com/page-25-get-keystore-in-unity-android
И все. Ключ с консоли можете выкинуть.